# How to import updated records in filemaker

Tags: filemaker

I extorted data as csv file form somewhere and then i m trying to import this csv file into filemaker. But i want to import only those records which are not available in that filemaker database.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to directly import only new records. Here is a possible work-around, though. I assume that the goal is to import into your current table, `final destination table`

1. Create a new `temporary import` table.
2. Create a relationship between the `temporary import` table and `final destination table`. Usually you'd want to do this based on a unique key that is in the csv file as well as the record on your `final destination table`.
3. If you are doing this manually, create a layout showing the `temporary import` table which has the related index from the `final destination table`: `final destination table::unique key`. (If you are writing a script to do this process automatically, this won't need to be done.)
4. Import the csv file to the `temporary import` table.
5. Enter `Find Mode` on the layout of the `temporary import` table, enter `*` into the `final destination table::unique key` field, set the record to be omitted, and then perform the find.
6. The layout should now only have records that are not already in the `final destination table`
7. Go to the `final destination table` and import from the `temporary import` table of the same database.

That should do it. Some additional discussion is available here: http://www.filemakertoday.com/com/showthread.php/29550-Importing-only-new-records